# Concatenating video files — Primere sees audio track only

Tags: video-editor

Like most, my camera splits files at a maximum length when it writes to the memory card.  I want to join them back up into one file = one take before loading the clips into Premiere, as that makes some things easier.

I’m running Windows, tried multiple versions of ffmpeg built for Win64.

The result plays in VLC just fine, but **Premiere sees it as audio-only!**  The maddening this is that this worked just fine in April, and the files I created then are still working in the current version of Premiere.

The command I use:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i cat.txt -c copy p:\scratch\out.mov
```

where the `cat.txt` contains two consecutive files from the camera, the first about 4GB and the second less than 2GB.

The newly created file shows the following with ffprobe:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.75.100
  Duration: 00:19:53.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31461 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29920 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 01:42:10:07
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 01:42:10:07
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

An older one that works shows:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
  Duration: 00:21:08.89, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30955 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29416 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 22:39:33:15
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      timecode        : 22:39:33:15
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

I’m trying an older version of ffmpeg, but it makes no difference.

I don’t remember having to do anything different before, and I can’t find any difference in the files.